# SE of RMSE in R

Tags: r, confidence-interval, cross-validation, chi-squared-distribution, rms

I have crossvalidated my models and measured RMSE between the modelled values and reality:

```
RMSE <- function(err) sqrt(mean(err^2))
RMSE(predicted - reality)
```

I am going to choose model with lowest RMSE. But I would like to know what difference in RMSE is still significant. I guess I could do some F-test comparisons, but as I have tens of models I don't like the idea of pairwise comparisons. This leads me to question

#### How can my RMSE function be extended to compute SE of RMSE?

How to do this in R? I guess this will be somehow based on Chi-square distribution parametrized by `length(err)` and maybe somehow scaled by `sd(err)` (?), but I don't know how to make this statistically correctly in R.

Comment: Someone posted [the same question](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/78079/5509) later.